# Cannot run my class because **context error in airflow

Tags: python, airflow, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to create a class where at least 1 task will be skipped so the dag will be "skipped" and it sends me an alert to my channel in slack.

I have an issue with the **context** it appears to me this error:

"from airflow.utils import context
ImportError: cannot import name 'context' from 'airflow.utils' (/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/**init**.py)"

this is my class:

```
class SkippedOperator:

    def __init__(self, channels, mode, **context):
        self.context = context
        self.env = ENV
        self.mode = mode
        self.task = context.get('task_instance').task_id
        self.dag = context.get('task_instance').dag_id
        self.exec_date = context.get('task_instance').exec_date
        self.log_url = context.get('task_instance').log_url
        self.channels = channels

    def _send_slack_alerts_v2(self, task_id, msg):
        tasks = []
        if ENV != 'prod':
            for channel in self.channels:
                alert = SlackAPIPostOperator(
                    task_id=task_id,
                    channel=channel,
                    slack_conn_id=SLACK_CONN,
                    text=msg,
                    username='airflow')
                tasks.append(alert.execute(context=self.context))

        if self.mode == 'failed':
            raise AirflowException("Number of skipped tasks in DagRun > 0")

    def task_skipped_slack_alerts(self):
        with closing(settings.Session()) as session:
            count = session.query(
                models.TaskInstance
            ).filter(
                models.TaskInstance.dag_id == self.context["dag"].dag_id,
                models.TaskInstance.execution_date == self.context["logical_date"],
                models.TaskInstance.state == State.SKIPPED).count()

        if count > 0:
            print(f"number of tasks in skipped status is {count}")
            slack_msg = """
                        :{circle}: {env} {task_mode}.
                        *Task*: {task}
                        *Dag*: {dag}
                        *Execution Time*: {exec_date}
                        """.format(
                circle=lambda x: 'red_circle' if self.mode == 'failed' else 'white_circle',
                task_mode=lambda x: 'Task Failed' if self.mode == 'failed' else 'Dag Success',
                env=self.env,
                dag=self.dag,
                exec_date=self.exec_date,
                task=self.task)
            return self._send_slack_alerts_v2(lambda x: 'slack_failed' if self.mode == 'failed' else 'slack_success',
                                              slack_msg)
```

and this is my dag:

```
Skipped_Task = SkippedOperator(channels='my_channel', mode='success', context=context)

@dag(dag_id="my_test_dag", default_args={
        'on_failure_callback': partial(task_fail_slack_alerts, [AIRFLOW_CHANNEL])},
     start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
     schedule_interval=None, catchup=False)
def generate_dag():
    start_task = DummyOperator(task_id="task1")

    @task()
    def task2():
        raise AirflowSkipException

    @task()
    def task3():
        return

    start_task >> [task2(), task3()] >> Skipped_Task

dag = generate_dag()
```

If someone knows what is the issue with the context that I'm trying to read from my class it will be wonderful :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `airflow.utils.context` module was not made [available as a module](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/20217) until Airflow 2.2.3. In order to use it, you'll need to upgrade to *at least* that version of Airflow.